# After installing babel I get an exception of undeclared variable

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

In my current project I have a lot of global variables:
(not declared with var)

```
HELLO = 'Hello';
```

I installed babel so I can use all the ES next functions, but it seems babel doesn't now how to deal with global variables

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    {
      "modules": "commonjs"
    }
  ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["angularjs-annotate"]
}
```

**UPDATE!!**

Seems that it comes from babel transpiling.
Babel added:  `"use strict";` . That's why my code failed

Comment: I think it want you to declare them all in the global scope from the start of your file with a line like : `var HELLO, OTHER_GLOBAL, AND_A_THIRD_ONE`

Comment: I can't do it right now. My project is huge and I don't know where are all the global variables

Comment: What is the exact and complete error message you are getting?

Comment: ReferenceError: `variable` is not defined (Where variable is the variable name)

Comment: You still should declare global variables with `var`, otherwise that assignment *is* an error in strict mode.

Comment: How did you configure your babel? Did it enable strict mode or modules?

Comment: @Bergi I edited my question. When I remove the commonjs, It works but I need it for another loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.
It takes me a while to figure it out.

here's the solution:
Add that to the plugins in .babelrc

```
"plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs", {
    "strictMode": false
  }],
      "angularjs-annotate"
  ]
```

Comment: While this technically works, this is not the recommended approach. The duplicate should explain better. Use [`sourceType`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#sourcetype)

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve global by assign var to the window
like so:

```
window.HELLO = 'hello';
```